# how to hide messages from ggplot in knitr

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I'm using RStudio to knit my R markdown document into a word file.

I have this chunk in the beginning of my document:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warnings=FALSE, messages=FALSE, results="hide")
```
````

But, I still keep have these messages inside my document after an histogram:

```
## `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
## Warning: Removed 686 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).
```

How can I make them go away?

Comment: try removing the "s" from `warnings` and `messages`. Here's the annotated list of syntactically correct knitr chunk options: http://yihui.name/knitr/options/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For this particular message, you can make it disappear by specifying the `binwidth` argument to `geom_histogram`.  This is good practise, so you should do it!

In general, you can suppress messages by setting `message = FALSE` as a [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results).

Answer (score 4):

The option to suppress this is now

```
, warning = F
```